# How do i pass value from User Control to another User Control

Tags: c#, user-controls

I need to pass a string that from my first UserControl to the second UserControl.
How do i do?

Comment: What is the type of your project? Winforms? WPF? Or...?

Comment: if this is just winforms, just use a *reference*,

Comment: It's a Winforms

Comment: Just hook up a reference in your forms consutructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define custom property to achieve it.

First, define property `UC2` in `Form1.cs` to access the `SecondUC instance`.

```
public SecondUC UC2
{
    get { return secondUC1; }
    set { secondUC1 = value; }
}
```

Then, define property `TB2` in `SecondUC.cs` to access the `TextBox instance` that in `SecondUC`.

```
public TextBox TB2
{
    get { return textBox2; }
    set { textBox2 = value; }
}
```

Last, set the `TextBox2` vaule by clicking button in `FirstUC`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form1 = (Form1)this.FindForm();
    form1.UC2.TB2.Text = "test string";
}
```

Test result,

[image]

Comment: What is a "secondUC1" ?

Comment: It's the name of SecondUC which you drag&drop from toolbox.

Comment: I can't find it in a toolbox. What name of it in toolbox?

Comment: Rebuild the project first.Then you can find it at the top of the toolbox. Its name is the same as the UserControl name you created.

Comment: Nothing Happened.

Comment: I'm already add those code to my project but in a Form it said " 'secondUC1' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Did you add the UserControl via `Project -> Add User Control..`?

Comment: Yes, i did. i named it Confirm.

Comment: After rebuilding, switch to another tab and then return to "From1[Designer]". Or close `toolbox` and reopen. Sometimes, toolbox can't refresh correctlly.

Comment: I found it! Thank you all!!

Comment: Glad to hear this.

Comment: @SaranDeeluea If this answer helps you, please click `√` to mark this as answer.